# Jquery Json The resource cannot be found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, select

I am trying to populate a drop down list with jquery in MVC. This is my code below.

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetTeams(StatisticModel model)
    {
        StatisticModel newModel = new StatisticModel(model.leagueId);
        var teams = newModel.getTeams;
        return Json(teams);
    }
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("GetTeams", "Admin"))
    {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
    <table class="addStatLeague">
    <tr><td>Choose League: </td><td><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.leagueId, Model.getLeagues, new { @class = "dropdownlistLeagueStyle" })%></td><td><input id="leagueButton" class="loginButton" value="GetTeams" type="submit" /></td></tr>
</table>

<select id="LeagueTeams"></select>
```

JquerY:

```
$(function() {
$(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Admin/GetTeams", { LeagueId: $(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").val() },
  function (teams) {
      $("#LeagueTeams").empty();
      $.each(teams, function (i, team) {
         $("#LeagueTeams").append($("<option>" + team.Text + "</option>"));
     });
  });
  });
   })
```

For some reason I am getting a resource not found error page as shown below.

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Admin/GetTeams

Comment: you get this error on page load or when you select an item in the dropdown?

Comment: when I select an item and press Get Team button

Comment: ok, then my solution should work. Can you get it working?

Comment: ok and should I use Html.Begin Form ?

Comment: the $.getJSON works now? only clicking on the button does not work?

Comment: well actually I dont know if the jquery works as I am not redirected to the method as page not found :S Is their anything different when using Json instead Of Using Html.Beginform ?

Comment: $.getJSON is an ajax function and the page is not refreshed. That's different from clicking the submit button (which will refresh the page)

Comment: Ok good so I can remove the html.Begin form right? now it should work when changing drop down list right?

Comment: yes, it should. Call alert(teams) inside `function (teams) {` to see if you get the json from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetTeams(StatisticModel model)
    {
        StatisticModel newModel = new StatisticModel(model.leagueId);
        var teams = newModel.getTeams;
        return Json(teams,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Another thing to check is model binding:

```
$.getJSON("/Admin/GetTeams", { LeagueId: $(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").val() }
```

should be:

```
$.getJSON("/Admin/GetTeams", { model: {LeagueId: $(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").val() }}
```

If `StatisticModel.LeagueId` on server side is `int`, you have to use `parseInt` on client side.

```
$.getJSON("/Admin/GetTeams", { model: {LeagueId: parseInt($(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").val()) }}
```

**Update:** consider using a simpler solution:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetTeams(int LeagueId)
{
    StatisticModel newModel = new StatisticModel(LeagueId);
    var teams = newModel.getTeams;
    return Json(teams,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Client side:

```
$.getJSON("/Admin/GetTeams", { LeagueId: parseInt($(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").val()) }
```

Comment: I am surrounding the league drop down list with : 

<% using (Html.BeginForm("GetTeams", "Admin"))
        {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>

Comment: @BuyMy Bet: you have to make sure that the controller name is "AdminController", and if your LeagueId on server side is int, you need parseInt on client side

Comment: @BuyMy Bet: so you need parseInt, check the last $.getJSON in my answer

Comment: nothing seems to work... could it be because ?

 <% using (Html.BeginForm("GetTeams", "Admin"))
        {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
        <table class="addStatLeague">
        <tr><td>Choose League: </td><td><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.leagueId, Model.getLeagues, new { @class = "dropdownlistLeagueStyle" })%></td><td><input id="leagueButton" class="loginButton" value="GetTeams" type="submit" /></td></tr>
    </table>


Check my updated View in post

Comment: @BuyMy Bet: the main problem is the route does not match, not the view. jQuery has problems serializing nested json objects into url-encoded string. Nested json object in your case is the `StatisticModel model`, you may have use a trick with "POST" and json data to get rid of it. There is a simpler approach, consider not using `StatisticModel model`, just use `int LeagueId`. This way the code on client side is `$.getJSON("/Admin/GetTeams", { LeagueId: parseInt($(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").val()) }`

Comment: ok can you kindly post a full code of how to do this pls in view controller and jquery